# Angular ui-date pre-populate bound data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am fairly new to SPA development, but I have not found the answer to this anywhere. I have a simple date-picker in my page:

```
<div>Select Date: <input type="text" ui-date ui-date-format="yy-mm-dd" ng-model="outputParam"></div>
```

In my controller, I set the value of outputParam

```
$scope.outputParam = new Date();
```

What I was hoping for was that the value of the bound variable would pre-populate in my UI, but when the page loads, it is blank.

I know the code to set the variable runs because of console logging I have added. I also know the variable is set to a value for the same reason.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to remove the `type="text"` from your input control.  ui-date handles the creation of the proper type itself.  Other than that, my only other guess would be to make sure you are including the ui-date source script in your includes.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that but it didn't seem to have any effect at all, good or bad. The date-picker control pops up fine if I click the "textbox" but what I am trying to do is get the box to show the "default" date when it loads. Also if I select a date, that date shows up in the box just fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I removed my format and it worked. I think your format is invalid. Try:

```
ui-date-format="yy-MM-dd"
```